# MySQL stored procedure doesn't do inserts as expected

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, insert

I am passing two arguments and I need to populate stats table with multiple insert call. It is not working, can anyone help me on this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STAT(IN arg_From DATETIME, IN arg_End DATETIME)

INSERT INTO stats(source_id_fk,source_type,stat_type_id_fk,
                 stat_count,modified_on,created_on)   
(SELECT -1 as source_id_fk ,3 as source_type, 1 AS stat_type_id_fk ,
                 COUNT( 1 ) AS stat_count, NOW( ) AS modified_on , 
                 NOW( ) AS created_on 
FROM  wall_posts WHERE post_type =1 
and created_on >= arg_From 
and created_on <= arg_End group by 1,2,3,5,6)

INSERT INTO stats(source_id_fk,source_type,stat_type_id_fk,stat_count,
                 modified_on,created_on) 
(SELECT -1 as source_id_fk ,3 as source_type, 2 AS stat_type_id_fk , 
                 COUNT( 1 ) AS stat_count  , NOW( ) AS modified_on , 
                 NOW( ) AS created_on 
FROM  wall_posts WHERE post_type =2  
and created_on >= arg_From 
and created_on <= arg_End group by 1,2,3,5,6);
```

Comment: Did you see `arg_eND` is like this in the definition but `arg_End` when inserting?

Comment: That happened when I was copying to StackOverFlow .

Comment: If you can, when posting a question involving code, it is worth taking a moment to make it as readable as possible. Someone has reformatted it for you, but it is kind to reduce this effort where possible.

Comment: Can you explain what _not working_ means in this case? What were you expecting? What actually happens? I don't think there is enough to go on here.

Comment: When I try to save this procedure in phpmyadmin it is not able to save it . But if I keep only one insert statement it executes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to end the first insert statement with `;`

To make MySQL not think that your procedure is finished there you have to encapsulate those multiple statements in a `BEGIN ... END` block and change the delimiter.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE STAT(IN arg_From DATETIME, IN arg_eND DATETIME)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO stats(source_id_fk,source_type,stat_type_id_fk,
                 stat_count,modified_on,created_on)   
(SELECT -1 as source_id_fk ,3 as source_type, 1 AS stat_type_id_fk ,
                 COUNT( 1 ) AS stat_count, NOW( ) AS modified_on , 
                 NOW( ) AS created_on 
FROM  wall_posts WHERE post_type =1 
and created_on >= arg_From 
and created_on <= arg_End group by 1,2,3,5,6);

INSERT INTO stats(source_id_fk,source_type,stat_type_id_fk,stat_count,
                 modified_on,created_on) 
(SELECT -1 as source_id_fk ,3 as source_type, 2 AS stat_type_id_fk , 
                 COUNT( 1 ) AS stat_count  , NOW( ) AS modified_on , 
                 NOW( ) AS created_on 
FROM  wall_posts WHERE post_type =2  
and created_on >= arg_From 
and created_on <= arg_End group by 1,2,3,5,6);
END $$
DELIMITER ; /*and change it back to the normal `;` again*/
```